# OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a strange problem. If I use cvCvtColor on an image it works but if I want to modify that image and use cvCvtColor on it there is an error:

> OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments
>   do not match () in cvCvtColor, file
>   /build/buildd-opencv_2.1.0-3-i386-PaiiLK/opencv-2.1.0/src/cv/cvcolor.cpp,
>   line 2208 terminate called after
>   throwing an instance of
>   'cv::Exception'

There shouldn't be this error because I have as output:

> targetImage->width =300,
>   targetImage->height =300  cap->width
>   =300, cap->height =300

that is: the size is the same. So it's nonsense..
Any idea of a possible solution?

The relevant code is here:

```
printf("\ntargetImage->width =%d, targetImage->height =%d ",targetImage->width,targetImage->height );

cap = cvCreateImage(cvSize(targetImage->width,targetImage->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvCvtColor(targetImage, cap, CV_BGR2GRAY);//HERE NO PROBLEM

CvRect xargetRect = cvRect(0,0,300,300);
subImage(targetImage, &showImg, xargetRect);
cap = cvCreateImage(cvSize(targetImage->width,targetImage->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
printf("\ntargetImage->width =%d, targetImage->height =%d ",targetImage->width,targetImage->height );
printf("\ncap->width =%d, cap->height =%d ",cap->width,cap->height );
cvCvtColor(targetImage, cap, CV_BGR2GRAY); //HERE THE PROBLEM
```

Thanks

This is the subimage code:

```
/// Modifies an already allocated image header to map
/// a subwindow inside another image.
inline void subImage(IplImage *dest, const IplImage *orig, const CvRect &r) {
   dest->width = r.width;
   dest->height = r.height;
   dest->imageSize = r.height * orig->widthStep;
   dest->imageData = orig->imageData + r.y * orig->widthStep + r.x * orig->nChannels;
   dest->widthStep = orig->widthStep;
    dest->roi = NULL;
   dest->nSize = sizeof(IplImage);
    dest->depth = orig->depth;
    dest->nChannels = orig->nChannels;
   dest->dataOrder = IPL_DATA_ORDER_PIXEL;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for subImage?

Comment: I've just seen your comment, sorry for the delay ;)

Comment: I think your `widthStep` and `imageSize` are both incorrect, you will have to recalculate those based on the new image's dimensions because of the subwindow.

Comment: Also see [this example](http://blog.weisu.org/2007/10/opencv-get-sub-image.html) for some different code to get a subimage.

Answer (score 0):

I now have a working dev environment, so I should post some code.

The error message in your question shows that you are using OpenCV 2.1.  I tried the code sample in OpenCV 2.2 and it works just fine, your `subImage` seems to be working as expected.  Though the `CvRect &r` parameter works as X,Y with width, height (as opposed to P1 to p2).  Below is the code I tried (minor modifications, but very same `subImage`):

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

/// Modifies an already allocated image header to map
/// a subwindow inside another image.
inline void subImage(IplImage *dest, const IplImage *orig, const CvRect &r)
{
    dest->width = r.width;
    dest->height = r.height;
    dest->imageSize = r.height * orig->widthStep;
    dest->imageData = orig->imageData + r.y * orig->widthStep + r.x * orig->nChannels;
    dest->widthStep = orig->widthStep;
    dest->roi = NULL;
    dest->nSize = sizeof(IplImage);
    dest->depth = orig->depth;
    dest->nChannels = orig->nChannels;
    dest->dataOrder = IPL_DATA_ORDER_PIXEL;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IplImage targetImage;
    IplImage* showImg = cvLoadImage("c:\\image11.bmp");

    //printf("\ntargetImage->width =%d, targetImage->height =%d ", targetImage->width, targetImage->height );

    //IplImage* cap = cvCreateImage(cvSize(targetImage->width, targetImage->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    //cvCvtColor(targetImage, cap, CV_BGR2GRAY);//HERE NO PROBLEM

    CvRect xargetRect = cvRect(100, 100, 100, 100);
    subImage(&targetImage, showImg, xargetRect);
    IplImage* cap = cvCreateImage(cvSize(targetImage.width, targetImage.height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    printf("\ntargetImage->width =%d, targetImage->height =%d ", targetImage.width, targetImage.height );
    printf("\ncap->width =%d, cap->height =%d ", cap->width, cap->height );
    cvCvtColor(&targetImage, cap, CV_BGR2GRAY); //HERE THE PROBLEM

    int result = cvSaveImage("c:\\image11.output.bmp", &targetImage);

    return 0;
}
```